# How to show number of total records for an associated model - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to be able to display the count for an associated model with specific conditions. I have a `Mall` model that has_many `Shops`, a `Shop` model which belongs_to `Mall` and has_many `Sales`, and a `Sale` model that belongs_to `Shop`.

Basically what I want to do is to first Iterate through each mall to display the :name of each mall, and then I would like to show how many total Sale records exist for shops belonging to each mall. However, I only want to show the number of Sale records with the following criteria: `Sale.where('offer_end >= ?', Date.today)`.

Im not really sure how to achieve this due to Sales not having a direct connection to Malls. The following code is my best attempt to achieve this but its not working.

```
<% @malls.each do |mall| %>
  <%= mall.name %> - <%= mall.shops.sales.where('offer_end >= ?', Date.today).count %>
<% end %>
```

Mall Model

```
class Mall < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :mall_shops
    has_many :shops, :through => :mall_shops
    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

Shop Model

```
 class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
    has_many :mall_shops
    has_many :malls, :through => :mall_shops
    has_many :sales, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Sale Model

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shop
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you can nest `has_many :through` associations:

**In Mall.rb:**

`has_many :sales, through: :shops`

You can also create a scope for active sales:

**In Sale.rb:**

```
scope :active, -> do
   where('offer_end >= ?', Date.today)   # Pay attention to time zone here
end
```

Now, you can get active sales for a mall:

```
@mall = Mall.find(...)
@mall.sales.active.count
```